# ValueError in Inverse Scaling

Tags: python, scikit-learn, recurrent-neural-network, scaling

I am building a RNN model and as I did for the training set, I need to scale my test data. I am running the code below and getting an error "ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (334,6) (7,) (334,6)". I checked the data I originally scaled and it does not have any NAs or something different in it.

##### inverse scaling for forecast

```
inv_yhat = concatenate((yhat, X_test[:, 1:]), axis=1)
inv_yhat = scaler.inverse_transform(inv_yhat)        
inv_yhat = inv_yhat[:,0]
```

##### The error:

```
> ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call
> last) <ipython-input-8-191de6d51a88> in <module>
>       3 # invert scaling for forecast
>       4 inv_yhat = concatenate((yhat, X_test[:, 1:]), axis=1)
> ----> 5 inv_yhat = scaler.inverse_transform(inv_yhat)          # min max scaler
>       6 inv_yhat = inv_yhat[:,0]
>       7 
> 
> D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\preprocessing\_data.py in
> inverse_transform(self, X)
>     459                         force_all_finite="allow-nan")
>     460 
> --> 461         X -= self.min_
>     462         X /= self.scale_
>     463         return X
> 
> ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes
> (334,6) (7,) (334,6)
```

It seems a simple error but I couldn't figure it out.

Comment: What is the shape of `inv_yhat` ?

Comment: (334, 6) @Kishore

Comment: Did you `fit` the `scaler` with data of same shape ?

Answer (score 0):

I found the error, thank you @Kishore for making me realise it.

When I was assigning features to X and y before train and test split, I went wrong and dropped a column from X. Therefore the shape of X_train became to (646, 1 , 6) and could not do the operation with the other shape that has 7 feature and gave the error.